# How to create a basket from a database table in orange(python package)?

Tags: python, orange

I am using Orange in python to do market basket analysis using a data in the database table. But I couldn't find a way to do that as it needs data in .basket type. 
Is there a way to load the data as a .basket type? I am using MsSQL as the database.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[**.basket* file format](http://docs.orange.biolab.si/reference/rst/Orange.data.formats.html#basket-format) seems basically just a list of values, optionally with count other than the implied 1:

```
v1, v2, v3=4
v2, v5
v1, v5, v6
...
```

IIRC, this implies a table like the following:

```
v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6
1   1   4   0   0   0
0   2   0   0   1   0
1   0   0   0   1   1
```

But is somewhat shorter (sparse) as all the zeroed values need not be represented.

Comment: So how to get data from database table and input?

Comment: If this question is about how to construct an SQL query that prints your database contents in the above format, then I guess you should tag the question as `SQL` as well. Since I know 0 MS SQL, it might be easiest to get a dump of data into a CSV and work from there ...